# On Ubuntu 20.4.3 Alt+Left Ctrl do not function as Alt Gr on Finnish layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

On windows Swedish/Finnish keyboard layout left ctrl + left alt works as right alt (Alt gr). On Ubuntu this does not work by default.

For example on Windows:
LeftCtrl + LeftAlt + '7' writes the '{' character.

On Ubuntu, on Finnish layout, nothing happens.

I do not except any 'solutions' where I have to set each individual special character button combination separately.
It would probably help if I new what the term 'chooser' means.
BTW: holding down alt gr and sliding my finger over all number keys gives:

1@£$5‚{[]}\

1 is not supposed to give anything but 5 should give the euro character which I am now unable to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses XKB keyboard layouts, and most layouts (including Swedish and Finnish) defines <kbd>AltGr</kbd> by default as the key to access 3rd level symbols.

On Ubuntu you can use *Tweaks* to pick some other key. But AFAIK it's not possible to choose a key combination such as <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftAlt</kbd> for that purpose.

Linux is not Windows, and when switching from one to the other you need to be ready to change your habits in some respects.

*Edit:*

On Lubuntu with LXQt you can open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and replace this line:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

with for instance

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt, lv3:lalt_switch"
```

and reboot. The example changes the key to access 3rd and 4th level symbols from <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>.

Comment: I am on Lubuntu and I installed gnome-tweaks. I could not find an option to set AltGr. Will you be able to provide a little more detail to help. Thanks.

Comment: @Champ: Tweaks does not work on Lubuntu with LXQt, which seems to [not provide a UI for the purpose](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1110) either. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi @gunnar-hjalmarsson thanks for your reply. I did as you suggest. But it simply switches current setting of alt-gr from right-alt to left-alt. For me, the AltGr simply prints english characters on the US keyboard. I use IBUS input method Hindi - inscript (m17n) and AltGr (Right Alt) just prints the english character defined on the key.

Comment: I had #ORIGINAL: XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
 and changed it to XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp" which did as commented above. I was able to select right alt using "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" and selecting right alt for AltGr. Posting here for completeness and necessary detail. Thanks.

Comment: @Champ: I'm confused. You originally had set <AltGr> as the key for accessing 3rd and 4th level symbols, but you said in your first comment: "I could not find an option to set AltGr". So maybe I misunderstood, and probably you should ask a separate question if you still need help to make it work.

Comment: Hi @gunnar-hjalmarsson Initially, I was having difficulty setting 'Right Alt' as the AltGr key but I was successful at that after using dpkg-reconfigure as mentioned in my comment above. But having set the AltGr key to 'Right Alt', I was not able to use it for accessing the 3rd and 4th level symbols. It just prints the English character on the key. So, I am still not able to access 3rd/4th level symbols. Thanks.

Comment: @Champ: Then edit `/etc/default/keyboard` again and drop the `lv3:ralt_alt` part.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your keyboard distribution has changed.

Try to setup following this (if you are using KDEPlasma):

- open System Configuration.
- in the input textbox type "keyboard"
- click on "keyboard" (Hardware > input devices > keyboard).

In that place, find for "distribution" tab and at the end is the distribution list. Find that you want (for you location).