# German Keyboard Layout "ctrl + alt + [random key]" does not work like "alt gr + [random key]" for Ubuntu 22.04, but it should

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

The title says it all:

German Keyboard Layout "ctrl + alt + [random key]" does not work like "alt gr + [random key]" for Ubuntu 22.04, but it should

As example, "ctrl + alt + q" should get @, or "ctrl + alt + e" should get €, at least that is what I am used to, using windows.

All I can find are either very outdated posts from 10 years ago, that are not applicable anymore or people telling me to just use "alt gr + [random key]" and to stop crying. I know I can use "alt gr + [random key]", but I don't want to.

I do not want to set new shortcuts where I would have to assign every single "alt gr + [random key]" to a new "ctrl + alt + [random key]" combination, but I just want to set "ctrl + alt" equal to "alt gr" for all keys.

My PC is a Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 with normal German keyboard layout, Ubuntu 22.04 was installed 2-3 weeks ago and all normal updates/upgrades have been made.

You guys would really help me out here a lot, because I am extremely used to this combination-style!

Edit: the suggested question [Unable to produce special Signs like @ on German keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457977/unable-to-produce-special-signs-like-on-german-keyboard-layout) has no solution as well, it just describes the problem in a more narrow way. So I don't think it is a good thing to close my question.

Comment: A question about the same topic was submitted [yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457977/unable-to-produce-special-signs-like-on-german-keyboard-layout/). If you want to suggest a changed behavior, this is not the proper place. A bug report is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to produce special Signs like @ on German keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457977/unable-to-produce-special-signs-like-on-german-keyboard-layout)

Comment: Windows is alone in making Ctrl+Alt be AltGr, this not a valid behavior on Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Ubuntu 20.4.3 Alt+Left Ctrl do not function as Alt Gr on Finnish layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377951/on-ubuntu-20-4-3-altleft-ctrl-do-not-function-as-alt-gr-on-finnish-layout)